# Getting 401 error when trying to start my bigcommerce theme locally

Tags: bigcommerce

Im trying to setup my bigcommerce theme locally. When I do stencil init I provide url, access token and port. After I go stencil start my localhost returns me 401 error.

I was able to run bigcommerce theme locally two weeks ago and now Im getting 401? Is there any chance that token is change or something like that?

Every advice would be helpful, tnx on your time! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you come back in to work on your local files, you shouldn’t have to run stencil init again. One should only run stencil init when setting up the local environment initially, as this command interactively creates a .stencil file,  which configures how to run a BigCommerce store locally. Could you check to see if you now have two of these files, as that possibly could cause an error.

Since you had your local working two weeks ago, all you would need to do is navigate to the directory where your files are located and run ‘stencil start’ to get your local running on your local host. No need to update any configurations or settings.

For troubleshooting the Stencil CLI, check these Stencil CLI Docs out!
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/installing-stencil-cli/stencil-cli-options-and-commands
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/installing-stencil-cli/troubleshooting-your-setup

Also, this article on common stencil errors may be helpful!
https://medium.com/bigcommerce-developer-blog/common-stencil-cli-pitfalls-and-how-to-avoid-them-7562dbbab793?source=friends_link&sk=ecb93332caf6b10d9ad858581d60add0